# tomcat runs multiple applications, but I need only one

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I don't know how to clean a TomCat server. When I launch an application, tomcat automatically runs all the applications that were previously launched by him. On settings "Add and Remouve" I have removed all applications that shouldn't be running, but it doesn't work. How can i clean up tomcat from apps that i don't want to run?

Comment: Please provide some details on how you deploy applications. There is no _"Add and Remove"_ setting in any software bundled with Tomcat, are you starting Tomcat from your IDE (Eclipse?)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I deploy app using ide Eclipse or Ij. I do so: Run as-> "run on server"->choose server (tomcat9 or tomcato8, or tomcat10)->next->"add and remouve"(here I can see all app available)->finish. And tomcat stars his work. But tomcat deploy all app available in the section "add and remouve".

Answer (score 2):

The solution is: go to the Tomcat folder-> go to webapps foder->delete all wars of the others project.